# Extend configuration from server in Plugin

Tags: sonarqube

We have a SonarQube-Server and locally in my Eclipse I have installed SonarQube-Plugin.
In my (local) Project I have a package, which I want to exclude from SonarQube-Analyze.
Therefore I added to the "Preview Analysis Proberties" in Eclipse the "sonar.exlusions"-Property.
This works well, BUT setting this property overrides the property set on the SonarQube-Server.
I do not want to overwrite it, I just want to extend it.

For example, the rule on the SonarQube-Server is "**/aUselessPackage/**/*" and my local rule is "**/myPackage/**/*". When I set this rule, "aUselessPackage" will be analyzed, because I overwrite the Server-property, but I want to exclude "**/aUselessPackage/**/*,**/myPackage/**/*".

Comment: What is your use case that makes you want to have different exclusions between a full analysis and a preview analysis in Eclipse?

Comment: I have a package in my Eclipse that will not be committed to the repository, I only use it local.

Comment: If it doesn't break the analysis and it just pulls down the code quality, it maybe best to fix the code quality. Even if the package is never used in production it is still worth it, because it is the perfect training ground to improve your own coding style.